# Setting D+ D- ports to set 12V From Qualcomm QC Chargers

Tags: usb, 12v, charge

I have a Qualcomm charger that I would like to output a constant 12V/ 20V. I know phones and tablets that support QC protocols set D+ and D- for different voltages (as in picture below). I'm wondering if the attached below picture will allow me to get say +12V from the charger safely and is it a electrically sound idea? Or should I just regulate from the VBUS itself? [image]

Comment: were you able to make this work? I have tried this schematic, but cannot get 12V to work. Using Xiaomi 20000mAh powerbank that is QC2.0 compatible. Load was a 12V led strip.

Answer (score 1):

Tried on mi 20000mAh powerbank.
It works, but you need to do this before using the table to set appropriate D+ and D- to adjust voltage output.

According the description in the CHY100 datasheet, the processes to enter QC2.0 are:
2.2 E-fuse and Interface
− − −
Apply a voltage between 0.325 V and 2 V to D+ for at least 1.25 seconds
Discharge the D- voltage below 0.325 V for at least 1ms while keep the D+ voltage above 0.325 V Apply the voltage levels in Table 3 to set the output voltage. (must keep the D+ voltage above 0.325 V)