# Can I power 12v devices from USB-C?

Tags: 12v, usb-c

First post, and I hope I'm in the right place.

Long story short, I have some led strips that normally draw power from a car battery, or large AGM via battery clamps. Well, I'm tired of having to carry around large heavy batteries. For Christmas, the wife got me a Ravpower Portable battery pack (Ravpower Super-C Series 26800) that has 2 USB ports and a USB-C port. Spec on the USB-C output says it will do 15V/2A. The draw on my lights are 12V/2A. I could probably get away with 10.5v or 11v.

Anyway, I've been looking high and low for a way to go from USB-C to 12V. The only thing I've seen is a small adapter on eBay that converts C to a barrel jack but, I've read that it will only put out 5v because of the way USB-C "detects" the device it is hooked up to and adjusts the voltage accordingly. I think that if there isn't a cable or product that allows you to do so, developing one would be a great idea. Especially for someone like me who has so many uses for 12v (lights, mobile drone battery charging, cpap machine) but, doesn't want to be limited to large batteries or Portable chargers with the 12v barrel already in them.

So, if anyone has any ideas as to where to begin to look for a solution to my problem, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting D+ D- ports to set 12V From Qualcomm QC Chargers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278663/setting-d-d-ports-to-set-12v-from-qualcomm-qc-chargers)

Comment: I think I may have found my answer at https://www.tindie.com/products/ReclaimerLabs/usb-type-c-power-delivery-phy-breakout-board/

Comment: Or maybe not. Which "a rawpower charger" do you have? There are dozens of models...

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/RAVPower-Portable-26800mAh-Recharged-Nintendo/dp/B01LRQDAEI/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1517553129&sr=8-4&keywords=ravpower+26800

Comment: It looks like the board from tindie you found will give you the interface, it won't do the things on its own. Meaning that you need to connect some other device that will use the board to negotiate with the USBc device for the voltage and current that you want. For instance, program a microcontroller that will request 12V 2A over the I2C interface.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353558/powering-12v-device-from-5-9-12v-powerbankSee also this Q&A from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your RAVPower-Portable charger uses Power Delivery protocol to increase voltage on Type-C connector. Unfortunately, it looks like the 12-V profile is missing from delivery options, and the charger doesn't support any more flexibility.

The breakout dongle for PD will work only if you attach to it a micro-controller with I2C interface, and program it to send proper negotiating inquires. It looks like the owner of this dongle offers some libraries for that. Still it is unlikely that you will get 12 V output.